# Map an array to an array

Tags: ruby, arrays, hashmap

I have an array of data and an array of keys that are in a specific order:

```
original_data = ['hello', 'world', 'one', 'two']
keys = [:greeting, :location, :first, :second]
```

I would like to map the keys to the data to be able to reference each datum by a key like this.

```
data[:greeting].should == original_data[0]
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be:

```
data = Hash[keys.zip original_data]
```